# Joomla same menu aliases

Tags: joomla, menu, alias, aliases

I am using Joomla in version 3. I have a problem with aliases, which may not be the same.

I am building a website that will work in this way:

There is a database of user profiles. A single user profile has its own specific menu that is configurable by the owner of the profile. Each menu must have at least one item called news.

The problem is this, I can not create a menu with the same alias. even if the parent is different, and I care about URLs which they would look like this:

www.abc.def / john-smith / news

www.abc.def / sam-jones / news

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you first create a Menu-item called john-smith you should be able to make the news menu under it with the right alias.

If joomla routing is not permitting this you have no choice and must replace it with a better routing - for instance sh404-sef should do the trick (its a paid SEF tool)